# Is it possible to load only one specific object from the model(document) when initializing the document in the Forge viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge

We would like to know if it possible to initialize the viewer to only render an specific object id.

There is a tutorial to extract geometry from a model, but it involves using the derivative to convert geometry to OBJ.
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/extract-geometry-from-source-file/

The idea is to create a catalog of objects based on the elements in a model (document). We usually work with Revit files.

Answer (score 0):

Viewer works with dbIds (or nodeIds which are equivalent to objectIds) and may load bubbles (geometry constructs) selectively based on - see live sample [here](https://jsbin.com/zidolot/edit?html)

```
viewer.loadModel(svfUrl,{ids:[dbIds...]})
```